# How to draw a chessboard with greek notation for the squares?

Tags: greek, chess, chessboard

How could I typeset a chessboard using greek notation for the squares?

I kind of manage to do it using `moreenum` but it uses math fonts while I would prefer to use normal fonts. Does anyone have any idea?

If possible, I'd rather have a XeLaTeX compatible solution

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage{chessboard}
\usepackage{moreenum}
\begin{document}
\chessboard[%
    setwhite={Qa1,Qd2},%
    showmover=true,%
    labelbottomformat=\greek{filelabel},%
]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need some font with greek chars.

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage{chessboard}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Lucida Sans Unicode}
\begin{document}

\def\mygreeklabelformat{\normalfont\char\numexpr944+\the\value{filelabel}\relax}


\chessboard[%
    setwhite={Qa1,Qd2},%
    showmover=true,%
    vlabelformat=\mygreeklabelformat,%
]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Ulrike, that def line was exactly what I was searching for :)